# Facebook publish_actions error

Tags: publish-actions

For Items in Review I am trying to submit a review for an iOS app and keep getting an error for "publish_actions" item as:

> "It looks like you haven't made any API requests to publish content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days. You, or any account from Roles, needs to test this app with this permission before you can submit it for review."

I've tried posting content on Facebook Wall Feed as a developer using my app and the post is showing on FB wall feed successfully. But the error doesn't seem to go away.

Any help on this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Login from your app with the account with which you have registered the app.

Request all the features and permissions that you need through the app (code).

Then go to the developer website. This message would have been removed.

Get your app reviewed.

Hope this helps :)